# How to find pythagoras triplet using the fibonacci sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers, pythagorean-triples

I'm using the Fibonacci sequence to generate some Pythagorean triples $(3, 4, 5,$ etc$)$ based off this page:[*Formulas for generating Pythagorean triples*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples)  starting at "*Generalized Fibonacci Sequence*".

For Fibonacci numbers starting with $F_1=0$ and $F_2=1$ and with each succeeding Fibonacci number being the sum of the preceding two, one can generate a sequence of Pythagorean triples starting from $(a_3, b_3, c_3) = (4, 3, 5)$ via $$(a_n, b_n, c_n) = (a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}, F_{2n-1}-b_{n-1}, F_{2n})$$

for $n \ge 4$.

I am unable to generate Pythagorean triplet sequence using Fibonacci series.

Kindly Help!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should get something like

```
n   Fib_{2n-1}  Fib_{2n}    a_n b_n c_n
3       3           5       4   3   5
4       8           13      12  5   13
5       21          34      30  16  34
6       55          89      80  39  89
7       144         233     208 105 233
8       377         610     546 272 610
```

etc.

Comment: But i have to generate pythagoraes triplet ,,

where is the case {6,8,10} etc. @Henry

Comment: @AdityaSharma: Try to calculate $a_n^2+b_n^2-c_n^2$ from the values in my table.  It generates *some* Pythagorean triplets, not all of them.

Comment: where is the case {6,8,10},etc....

in your case a_n^2+b_n^2-c_n^2=0

Comment: *some* not *all*

Comment: but i want to generate all triplets , how to generate them?

Comment: For non-negative positive integers $l,m,n$, you can generate all Pythagorean triples from  $a = 2lmn,\quad b=l(m^2-n^2),\quad c=l(m^2+n^2)$

Answer (score 1):

The following and many other related relationships can be found at [Dan Kalman's web pages.](http://www.dankalman.net)

w; x; y; and z are any four consecutive Fibonacci numbers

a = product of Outers (wz)

b = Twice Inners (2xy)

c = Firsts And Lasts (wy + xz)

(a; b; c) is a Pythagorean Triple!